# Simular Enter en Batch

Tags: batch, amazon-s3

Tengo un script que me descarga automáticamente el backup de un S3. Lo malo es que me pide una confirmación con un enter después de introducir la contraseña así que no es automático al 100%. ¿Alguien sabe si existe alguna forma de simular un enter?

He probado con usar el type de un .txt con un solo enter pero no me ha funcionado:

```
type archivo_con_un_enter.txt | script.bat
```

Aquí os dejo el script:

```
set ano=%date:~6,4%
set mes=%date:~3,2%
set dia=%date:~0,2%
cd %ProgramFiles%\S3 Browser
s3browser-con
s3browser-con.exe download Server:[password] bucket/%ano%-%mes%-%dia%/ C:\Backup
```

Comment: igual esto te ayuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071885/how-to-click-a-button-using-a-batch-file#13081018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que el password debería ir después de Server, tal que así (sin corchetes)

```
s3browser-con.exe download Server:mi_password bucket/%ano%-%mes%-%dia%/ C:\Backup
```

Lo probaste así tal cual?

Si no, otra opción sería probar con

```
echo mi_password|s3browser-con.exe download Server:[password] bucket/%ano%-%mes%-%dia%/ C:\Backup
```